# parse rollback after a failed object update

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am using parse.com 
here is a scenario :
I have 2 Classes A and B

step 1: creating an object on Class A
step 2: create a pointer from Class B to the new created object (on class A).

I wish to role back - delete the Class A object if step 1 was successful and step 2 failed.

As of parse documentation i didn't see any rollback strategy built into the system.
what would be a best practice solution?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Parse offers an easy way to guarantee chaining operations, but this is how I'd do it in Swift:

```
let objectA = ClassA()
objectA.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { success, error in
    if success {
        objectB.objectA = A
        objectB.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
            if !success {
                objectA.deleteEventually()
                objectB.removeObjectForKey("objectA")
            }
        }
    }
}
```